# TestNG - dependsOnGroups attribute to not check for skipped tests

Tags: testng, integration-testing

we are using TestNG in version 6.8.8 for implementing our integration tests. The tests itself are categorized in multiple groups which depend on the one before.

Like 'Configuration' depends on Group 'Setup' and so on, so the configuration tests are only executed if setup is successful - that is perfect.

But if we want to skip one of the setup tests, cause it is not needed sometimes, the configuration group won't be executed (cause setup was not executed successfully).

For our tests it would be perfect if this dependsOnGroups check could only be notified if a test of a group really fails and ignore skipped tests.

Does somebody has experience with that?